# Does cypress produce any smell or allergens when planted indoors?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, plant-recommendations, office-gardening

I'm thinking about putting a cypress [(*Chamaecyparis*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chamaecyparis) onto my office desk which is in an open space, however, I don't want it to disturb my coworkers.

Is an indoor cypress known to produce any notable smell, or emit allergens into the air?

Answer (score 4):

It does have a noticeable scent, but only if you bruise the leaves, usually. Any allergic response via the air is mostly restricted to when the plant flowers, which is unlikely indoors - it's the pollen that can cause a nasal response in sensitised people. Otherwise, some people may experience contact allergy after brushing against it.